# SSH to EC2 instance from home computer with variable IP address

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I currently run a web site from my basement and have a more expensive Internet service that includes a static IP address. I would like to move my website onto an AWS VPC. I have, so far, set up a default VPC and an instance with an elastic IP address. I have also set up public and private keys that enable me to ssh to the instance using PuTTY.

I have noticed that, when I use a VPN (like HotSpot Shield) which changes my IP address, I cannot ssh to my EC2 instance. Apparently, access to my EC2 instances is restricted via my security groups to only a few public IPs.

My question is this. If I change my home Internet service to a cheaper service that does not include a static IP address, will I sill be able to ssh to my EC2 instance? I could perhaps set up a bastion host and allow ssh from 0.0.0.0/0 to the bastion host. But is there a better/easier way to ssh to my EC2 instance if my Internet service does not include a static IP address?

Comment: Maybe the spineless keyboard commandos, who are thumbing my perfectly legitimate question down, might have the backbone to say why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can still SSH into your instance as long as the security group is updated to allow SSH from your current IP address. When I am in this situation I use a small script that gets my current IP and then uses the AWS CLI to update the security group.

You can `cURL` a site like [icanhazip.com](https://major.io/icanhazip-com-faq/) to get your IP address:

```
curl -4 https://icanhazip.com/
```

And then update the security group with your IP:

```
aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-name my-sg --protocol tcp --port 22 --cidr 203.0.113.0/24
```

(Example taken from the [AWS docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-ec2-sg.html).)

Of course it is best to remove any old SSH rules from the security group when you do make the update.